# Need Software to view and record ip camera

Tags: ip, camera, playback, h264

I have a Zmodo camera that is no longer supported. The app I have for it is 32 bit from Windows XP days. I don’t use windows and would like to find an ip camera app that supports h264 format for Ubuntu.  I have several laptops running different versions of Ubuntu from 12 to 20. If there is an app that has Ubuntu version dependencies I will use that version. Thank you!

Comment: That should be XP not Xperia

Comment: You can [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1329273/edit), to modify parts of it or to add more details, if you want. For example you could add in which version and which variant of Ubuntu you use.

Answer (score 0):

iSpy is an open source security camera software that works great on Linux and Windows from the times I have used it. You can find it on here:

https://www.ispyconnect.com/